# Constructing simple function for a product

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f,g:X\to \Bbb R_+$ be two measurable functions for some $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Suppose that for some constant $c\geq 0$ and any $x\in X$ it holds that $f(x)g(x)\geq c$. Is it possible for any $\delta>0$ to construct simple functions $f',g':X\to\Bbb R_+$ such that $f'\leq f$ and $g'\leq g$ and $f'(x)g'(x)\geq c - \delta$?

By a simple function I mean a measurable function that takes a finite number of values, e.g.
$$
  f'(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i 1_{X_i}(x)
$$
where $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a measurable partition of $X$, and $1_A:X\to \{0,1\}$ is an indicator function of set.

Comment: Do you require that $f'$ and $g'$ are nonnegative?

Comment: @richard: yes, sorry - I will add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible in general.

For example, let $X=(0,+\infty)$ endowed with Borel $\sigma$-algebra, let $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $c=1$. If $0\le f'\le f$ is a simple function, then there exists $M>0$, such that $f'\le M$. Then for every $g'\le g$ and every $x\ge 2M$, $f'(x)g'(x)\le Mg(x)\le \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I think you are right, I rather should ask whether it is possible to find $f'g'\geq c-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @Ilya: Yes, it would be better if you change your question like that.

Comment: done, thanks ${{}}$

Comment: @Ilya: You are welcome. I also edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Very nice, thanks!

Comment: @Ilya: You are welcome!